# Is right-shifting an unsigned integer by its total number of bits UB ?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I wanted to check that some big calculated memory needs (stored in an `unsigned long long`) would be roughly compatible with the memory model used to compile my code.

I assumed that right-shifting the needs by the number of bits in a pointer would result in 0 if and only if memory needs would fit in the virtual address space (independently of practical OS limitations).

Unfortunately, I found out some unexpected results when shifting a 64 bit number by 64 bits on some compilers.

Small demo:

```
const int ubits =  sizeof (unsigned)*8;  // number of bits, assuming 8 per byte
const int ullbits =  sizeof (unsigned long long)*8; 
cout << ubits << " bits for an unsigned\n"; 
cout << ullbits << " bits for a unsigned long long \n";

unsigned  utest=numeric_limits<unsigned>::max();  // some big numbers
unsigned long long ulltest=numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max();

cout << "unsigned "<<utest << " rshift by " << ubits << " = "
    << (utest>>ubits)<<endl; 
cout << "unsigned long long "<<ulltest << " rshift by " << ullbits << " = "
    << (ulltest>>ullbits)<<endl;
```

I expected both displayed rshit results be 0.

This [works as expected with gcc](http://ideone.com/zgS3nw).

But with MSVC 13 :

- in 32 bits debug:  the 32 bit rshift on unsigned has NO EFFECT ( displays the original number) but the 64 bit shift of the unsigned long long is 0 as expected.
- in 64 bits debug: the rshift has NO EFFECT in both cases.
- in 32 and 64 bits release: the rshif is 0 as expected in both cases.

I'd like to know if this is a compiler bug, or if this is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I have marked this as a duplicate. Even though the other question is not exactly the same, those answers also answer this question, providing references to the spec and rationale.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the C++ Standard (5.8 Shift operators)

> 1. ...**The behavior is undefined** if the right operand is negative, or  greater than or **equal to** the length in bits of the promoted
>      left operand

The same is written in the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 3 The integer promotions are performed on each of the operands. The
>   type of the result is that of the promoted left operand. If the value
>   of the right operand is negative or **is greater than or equal to the
>   width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined**.